# const monthParsed = new Date(Date.parse(`${3} 1, ${1992}`)).getMonth(); const yearParsed = parseInt(1992, 0);

Tags: javascript

```
const monthParsed = new Date(Date.parse(`${3} 1, ${1992}`)).getMonth();  
const yearParsed = parseInt(1992, 0);   
console.log(new Date(yearParsed, monthParsed, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).toISOString());
```

if I run the above code month was displaying like -> 1992-02-29T18:30:00.000Z but I want to display the output as 1992-03-29T18:30:00.000Z

Comment: Please write a better more descriptive title.

Answer (score 0):

`getMonth` returns a zero-indexed month - you need to add one to get the value you want: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth